# How to query Work Item links with specified comment using WIQL

Tags: tfs, wiql

I need a fast way to get a list of links filtered by the link comment.
Have a code:

```
var linkCommentFilter = "Some link comment";
const string queryString = @"SELECT [System.Id]
                               FROM workItemlinks
                               WHERE [System.Links.LinkType] = 'Tested By'
                               AND [System.Links.Comment] = '{0}'
                               AND ([Source].[System.Id] IN ({1}))";

var query = new Query(store, string.Format(queryString, 
    linkCommentFilter,
    string.Join(",", wiIds)));
var result = query.RunLinkQuery().ToArray();
```

When trying to run this code an exception occurred "field System.Links.Comment doesn't exist". How could I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't query Work Item links with specified comment using WIQL as there is no `System.Links.Comment` field in TFS.

You need to use TFS rest api to [get a list of work items with links and attachments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments), check the sample code below:

```
 public List<WorkItem> GetWorkItemsWithLinksAndAttachments()
        {
            int[] workitemIds = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 10, 22, 50 };

            VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            List<WorkItem> workitems = workItemTrackingClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(workitemIds, expand: WorkItemExpand.Links | WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result;

            foreach(var workitem in workitems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Work item {0}", workitem.Id);

                foreach (var relation in workitem.Relations)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0} {1}", relation.Rel, relation.Url);
                }
            }
```

Then find the specified comment with `relation.Attributes["comment"]` in `workitem.Relations`.